# Importing a Header File and Having .m Changes Carry Over in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, header, sdwebimage

For my first iPhone app, I've been using SDWebImage on Github to pull images from the internet.

This package comes with a `SDWebImage.framework`. I've been able to import that header file with `"#import SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h` which is fine so far.

However, I needed to make the cache time much shorter, so after reading some on this subject, I imported the package's Xcode project into my app. By adding those files, I can now see a WebImageCache.m file separate from the header files in the framework. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get my work in the .m file to impact how my view controller imports `SDWebImage`. I've found where I need to change the maxCacheAge, but it's no good if I can't get Xcode to read it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the framework or you'll have the same class/category twice -- copy the header next to the m file in your project